# Count в значение таблицы mysql

Tags: mysql, count

Интересует вопрос можно ли то таблицу в которой одно из полей будет содержать в себе количество записей из другой таблицы? В access вроде так делал уже. Если нельзя то какие есть альтернативы? Варианты с select отпадают нужно именно в базе хранить количество для последующей сортировки с помощью выборок

Comment: Будьте готовы к тому, что данные "расползутся" - т.е. заранее подготовьте процедуры пересчёта. _Варианты с select отпадают_ - приведённое обоснование как минимум не по делу. А получение количества записей в таблице (даже очень большой таблице) - операция весьма быстрая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов несколько.

1. **Создать для таблицы table1 представление  table1_view, в котором брать все поля table1 + вычислить поле "количество чего-то там"
   через select COUNT() from table2 ... можно подзапросом, а можно с
   помощью соединения таблиц и GROUP BY. В дальнейшем запросы из
   программы строить не к таблице а к view, можно будет сортировать по
   количеству и пр.**
2. Создать триггеры на добавление и удаление (а возможно и обновление,
   зависит от логики) в table2, которые будут
       обновлять вычислимые поля в table1, если уж так необходимо его
       именно хранить.

Кстати, зачем его вам именно *хранить* совершенно непонятно, это к тому же нарушает 3-ю нормальный форму. Но если уж действительно нужно (много чего бывает странного нужно) - вкусите триггеры. Рекомендуется, разумеется, первый вариант.

Comment: хранить для сортировки выводимой информации на стороне базы. просто с моей логикой программы сортировать проще всего выборками нежели jquery